# Is it possible to fix this gsub pattern?

Tags: string, lua, gsub

I'm messing around with Lua trying to create my own "scripting language".

It's actually just a string that is translated to Lua code, then executed through the use of loadstring.  I'm having a problem with my string patterns.  When you branch (for example, defining a variable inside of a variable declaration) it errors.  For example, the following code would error:

```
local code = [[
    define x as private: function()
        define y as private: 5;
    end;
]]
--defining y inside of another variable declaration, causes error
```

This is happening because the pattern to declare a variable first looks for the keyword 'define', and captures everything until a semicolon is found.  Therefore, x would be defined as:

```
function()
    define y as private: 5 --found a semicolon, set x to capture
```

I guess my question is, is it possible to ignore semicolons until the correct one is reached?  Here is my code so far:

```
local lang = {
    ["define(.-)as(.-):(.-);"] = function(m1, m2, m3) 
        return (
            m2 == "private" and " local " .. m1 .. " = " .. m3 .. " " or 
            m2 == "global" and " " .. m1 .. " = " .. m3 .. " " or
            "ERROR IN DEFINING " .. m1
        )
    end,
}

function translate(code)
    for pattern, replace in pairs(lang) do
        code = code:gsub(pattern, replace)
    end
    return code
end

local code = [[

    define y as private: function()
        define x as private: 10;
    end;

]]

loadstring(translate(code:gsub("%s*", "")))()
--remove the spaces from code, translate it to Lua code through the 'translate' function, then execute it with loadstring
```

Comment: Usually you need a recursive-like algorithm to handle these nested definitions. In your case, a simple pattern matching is not going to be easy to work with. I would recommend reading in the code word by word and deciding how to handle the next word. This would be like a custom parser for your own language.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to to change your last capture group from

```
(.-) -- 0 or more lazy repetitions
```

to

```
(.*) -- 0 or more repetitions
```

i.e.

```
pattern = 'define(.-)as(.-):(.*);'
```

The `-` modifier according to [PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) matches the shortest sequence.

However, as noted in my comment, I wouldn't advise writing a parser for your language using pattern matching. It will either require really complicated patterns (to prevent edge-cases) and probably be unclear to others.